# When clones died during battle what would they do with them afterwards?

Tags: star-wars, clones

If a clone died in battle, would he be buried there, left on the battlefield, or would they be taken somewhere else? We know they take count of casualties but I don't remember ever seeing anything with them after the battles, including burial grounds. Has this facet of Clone Wars-era battle ever been explained in Star Wars media?

Comment: Soylent green is <spoiler>